meaning of t-statistic of annualised portfolio returns
When a paper reports that a portfolio has an annualised return of 20% (t=6.5) what is the t-statistic related to? I guess it is a simple regression (in which case f-statistic and t-statistic are the same) but a regression of what?
I'd appreciate any pointers to read up on this.

An OLS time series regression of the excess return of a portfolio on a constant: It's a t-statistic for the test if the mean return is statistically significantly different from zero. If you throw in some factors as explanatory variables, then you report the intercept with its t-statistics as the ``alpha'' of the portfolio.

Thanks - what would you use as the risk free rate? A zero-rate for the holding period? If I rebalance portfolio every month, is my risk free rate the 1M zero-coupon rate?
